# Check for a value in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I need to find out if an id occurs in my JSON object, for example:

```
{
  "requested": "2009-07-25T14:12:25+01:00",
  "channels": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "General", "created": "2009-07-25 14:00:02"}
  ]
}
```

Specifically I need to check if my id (say, 2) occurs in `channels.`*`i`*`.id`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var id = 2,
    found = false;
for (var i=0; i<channels.length; i++) {
    if (channels[i].id == id) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more succinctly and probably faster :

```
var id = 2; 
for (var found, i = channels.length; i && !(found = channels[--i].id === id);)
  ;
```

Comment: @Gumbo's answer is much clearer though, and I doubt there's a significant speed difference, if any.

Comment: I think you meant `channels[--i].id`